# getting string from utf8 in android

Tags: android, string, webview

```
String strArr[]={"à¤¸à¤¾à¤‚à¤–à¥à¤¯à¤¯à¥‹à¤—",
         "'à¤•à¤°à¥à¤®à¤¯à¥‹à¤—",
        "à¤œà¥à¤žà¤¾à¤¨à¤•à¤°à¥à¤®à¤¸à¤‚à¤¨à¥à¤¯à¤¾à¤¸à¤¯à¥‹à¤—",
         "à¤•à¤°à¥à¤®à¤¸à¤‚à¤¨à¥à¤¯à¤¾à¤¸à¤¯à¥‹à¤—",
         "à¤†à¤¤à¥à¤®à¤¸à¤‚à¤¯à¤®à¤¯à¥‹à¤—",
        "à¤œà¥à¤žà¤¾à¤¨à¤µà¤¿à¤œà¥à¤žà¤¾à¤¨à¤¯à¥‹à¤—"};
```

I have `UTF-8` code like this when I have converted into string am getting like:

```
सा�?�?्यय�?�?'�?र्मय�?�?�?्�?ान�?र्मस�?न्यासय�?�?�?र्मस�?न्यासय�?�?�?त्मस�?यमय�?�?
�?्�?ानवि�?्�?ानय�?�?सा�?�?्यय�?�?'�?र्मय�?�?�?्�?ान�?र्मस�?न्यासय�?�?�?र्मस�?
न्यासय�?�?�?त्मस�?यमय�?�?�?्�?ानवि�?्�?ानय�?�?सा�?�?्यय�?�?'�?र्मय�?�?�?्�?ान�?
र्मस�?न्यासय�?�?�?र्मस�?न्यासय�?�?�?त्मस�?यमय�?�?�?्�?ानवि�?्�?ानय�?�?सा�?�?्यय�?
�?'�?र्मय�?�?�?्�?ान�?र्मस�?न्यासय�?�?�?र्मस�?न्यासय�?�?�?त्मस�?यमय�?�?�?्�?ानवि�?्
�?ानय�?�?सा�?�?्यय�?�?'�?र्मय�?�?�?्�?ान�?र्मस�?न्यासय�?�?�?र्मस�?न्यासय�?�?�?
त्मस�?यमय�?�?�?्�?ानवि�?्�?ानय�?�?सा�?�?्यय�?�?'�?र्मय�?�?�?्�?ान�?र्मस�?न्यासय�?
�?�?र्मस�?न्यासय�?�?�?त्मस�?यमय�?�?�?्�?ानवि�?्�?ानय�?�?सा�?�?्यय�?�?'�?र्मय�?�?
�?्�?ान�?र्मस�?न्यासय�?�?�?र्मस�?न्यासय�?�?�?त्मस�?यमय�?�?�?्�?ानवि�?्�?ानय�?�?
```

please anyone help to get proper string value!

[EDIT]
Code:

```
public static String convertFromUTF8(String s) {
   String out = null; 
   try { 
      out = new String(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
   } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
      return null; 
   } return out; 
}
```

Comment: code: public static String convertFromUTF8(String s) {
         String out = null;
         try {
             out = new String(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
         } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
             return null;
         }
         return out;
     }

Comment: Use their Unicode values instead of above. I had the same problem with degree character and having Unicode values instead fixed it.

Comment: A `String` just contains characters. It does not make sense to talk about converting it from one encoding to another. Encodings only play a role when you convert between bytes and `String`

Comment: @gunar Plz can you explain clearly

Comment: @Henry: I wouldn't be that sure ... If the IDE you're using has en exotic file encoding (as I assume patrioit has) it may look OK in the file. But when you compile and deploy you're in trouble. To not mention the case when you're using some source control or a continuous integration system. Having Unicode values for above chars  you'll standardize the String array to something that any file encoding can handle. And you would also be safe when using a source control system.

Comment: sorry still i am not clear!

Comment: @gunar Once you have a String it is just a sequence of characters. If the encoding of your source file does not match the encoding used by the java compiler, you made a mistake during the compilation. The point is, a String in Java does not carry an encoding with it. Internally, it is always represented as UTF-16

Comment: what is api level of your testing device/Emulator?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using eclipse:

1. right click your project > select properties
2. select "Resource" on the left
3. change text file encoding to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Try this site http://www.string-functions.com/encodedecode.aspx

Try to find source charset
and end charset of your string

then replace this line in yuor code

out = new String(s.getBytes("**CODE OF source charset**"), "**CODE OF end charset**");

Comment: Can you write the end string ? is it this one "鄐詮冗鄐,鄐-鄍鄐能仁鄍<鄐-" ?